# Add keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do keyboard shortcuts. For example, after clicking ctrl + b I got [b] [/ b]. I also want to have such a property that when I select the text with the mouse and click ctrl + b, I got [b] text [/ b]. My code currently looks like this:

html

```
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50">
lorem lorem lorem lorem 
    </textarea>
```

JQuery

```
var  textarea = $('#textarea');
textarea.mouseup(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var content = textarea.val(),
            selectText = window.getSelection().toString(),
            cursorPosition = textarea.prop('selectionStart'),
            content = textarea.val(),
            textBefore = content.substring(0, cursorPosition),
            textAfter = content.substring(cursorPosition, content.length);

        if(selectText.length > 0) {
            textarea.keyup(function (event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 66) {
                    textarea.val(content.replace(selectText, '[b]' + selectText + '[/b]'));
                    textarea[0].setSelectionRange(textBefore.length + selectText.length + 7, textBefore.length + selectText.length + 7);
                } });
        } else {
            textarea.keyup(function (event) {
                if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 66) {
                    textarea.val(textBefore + '[b][/b]' + textAfter)
                    textarea[0].setSelectionRange(textBefore.length + 7, textBefore.length + 7);
                } 
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I can't separate it into events. Because sometimes I want to select text and sometimes I just want to add a tag. At this point, my code works so that I always have to click the mouse on the field and then add a marker. And I can't add a few markers side by side.

To sum up my task is that after clicking ctrl + b in the field will appear `[b] [/ b]`, or after selecting the text and clicking ctrl + b will get `[b] text [/ b]`

[Live](https://jsbin.com/ticoguyoro/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of textarea.mouseup, do textarea.keydown. That way you can put your mouse down *and* press ctrl + b. I also changed the code a bit, without using keypress inside the function and making it more efficient.

```js
$('#textarea').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'b') {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    var start = this.selectionStart;
    var end = this.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = $(this).val().substring(start, end);
    var replacement = "[b]" + selectedText + "[/b]";
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start) + replacement + $(this).val().substring(end, length));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50">ducks</textarea>
```